# Quais arquivos de um projeto MEAN devo enviar ao GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Eu criei um projeto MEAN em MVC e estou querendo colocar no GitHub,
mas não sei ao certo o que enviar. Se tento enviar a pasta toda dá erro dizendo que são mais de 2 mil arquivos por causa dos módulos do NodeJS, Bower, etc. Então quais arquivos são realmente necessários enviar ao GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pastas do NPM e do Bower não precisam ser enviadas pro repositório. Essa é uma das vantagens de se utilizar um gerenciador de pacotes.

Para ignorar estes arquivos, você precisa criar um arquivo `.gitignore` na raiz do projeto.

O conteúdo do arquivo deve ser algo como:

```
/node_modules/
/bower_components/
```

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, tenha o [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) instalado e configurado em sua máquina.

Como você comentou, seu projeto tem muitos pacotes. Quando se usa um gerenciador de pacotes não é necessário enviar os pacotes para o repositório devido ao arquivo que contém a relação de todos os pacotes e dependências utilizados. Na maioria dos gerenciadores esse arquivo é o `package.json`.

Para evitar que os pacotes sejam enviados, crie um arquivo chamado [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). O conteúdo desse arquivo definirá quais pastas e arquivos não devem ser enviados para o controle de versão. Isso varia de ambiente para ambiente e de projeto para projeto.

No Mac, por exemplo, em todas as pastas é criado um arquivo `.DS_Store`, que tem alguns parâmetros do explorador de arquivos. Esse é um exemplo de arquivo que não deveria ser enviado para o Git.

Outra situação são alguns editores de texto ou IDEs, como o Visual Studio Code, que cria uma pasta `.vscode` com as configurações do editor/IDE específicas para seu projeto. Mais um que não deveria ser enviado.

Vou deixar um exemplo de `.gitignore` como eu faria em um ambiente como o seu:

```
/vendor/
/node_modules/
/bower_components/
.DS_Store
```

Com o `.gitignore` criado e o Git instalado você está pronto para enviar seu código para o GitHub. Se você ainda não criou um repositório Git local, siga os passos abaixo antes:

**Navegue até seu projeto.** Não sei se está usando Mac ou Windows, mas é simples nos dois casos. Abra o terminal no Mac ou o prompt de comando no Windows e navegue até a pasta raiz do seu projeto. Pode utilizar o comando `cd <caminho>` nesse caso em ambas as plataformas.

**Crie um repositório local.** Ainda utilizando a linha de comando, execute `git init` para criar o repositório.

**Dê commit no que você tem.** Execute `git add .` para adicionar todos os arquivos da pasta às suas alterações pendentes do commit. Enfim, execute `git commit -m "<mensagem qualquer>"` para efetivamente "*commitar*" no repositório local.

Ok, repositório local criado, agora para o GitHub.

**Crie um repositório GitHub.** Clique [aqui](https://github.com/new) e crie um novo repositório. Como você já tem um `.gitignore`, crie esse repositório sem ele.

**Adicione o seu repositório GitHub como remoto.** Use o comando `git remote add origin https://github.com/<seu_username>/<nome_repositorio>.git` para definir seu *repo* remoto.

**Faça um push das alterações locais para o remoto.** Rode o comando `git push -u origin master`.

Agora é só ir até `https://github.com/<seu_username>/<nome_repositorio>` para ver se tudo está lá como deveria estar.

Answer (score 2):

O Github tem um repositório com [exemplos de `.gitignore` típicos](https://github.com/github/gitignore). Um deles (link aqui) é o [`.gitignore` para o Node.js](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore).

A função do ficheiro `.gitignore` é exatamente não enviar para o Git ficheiros efémeros, ficheiros que só são precisos na compilação, e de modo geral todos os ficheiros que não fazem parte do código da aplicação.

Para os outros ficheiros há o `package.json` que indica as dependências e quais os ficheiros e suas versões para instalar com `npm install`.

O conteúdo desse `.gitignore` para Node.js é:

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# ficheiros gerados pelo servidor, temporários
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# diretoria da ferramenta jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# diretoria de ferramentas como o istanbul
coverage

# diretoria de respostas de testes de alguns programas
.nyc_output

# ficheiro temporário do Grunt
.grunt

# diretoria da ferramenta Bower
bower_components

# ficheiro de configuração de node-waf
.lock-wscript

# diretoria de ficheiros compilados (isto depende de que nome dás às pastas e se queres ou não ter ficheiros de release no Github)
build/Release

# Dependências
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# diretoria da ferramenta typescript
typings/

# diretoria da npm opcional
.npm

# diretoria do eslint opcional
.eslintcache

# log/hitoria de REPL
.node_repl_history

# Resultado de comprimir com 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Verificador de integridade do Yarn
.yarn-integrity

# variáveis do ambiente 
.env
```